Type 200 Xs as fast as possible

You want to type 200 “X”s as fast as possible. Each of the following procedures costs 1 second:

Typing 1 “X”
⁠Copy whatever you have written
⁠Paste whatever you copied

What’s the fastest way to reach at least 200 “X”?

My answer: type two Xs first (+2 secs), copy it and paste it 3 times (+4 secs), now copy all of this and paste it four times (+5 secs). Now we have 80 Xs. Next we copy this and paste it 2 times (+3 secs). We now have 240 Xs.
In total this strategy takes 14 seconds.
Is this the correct answer and is there a more concrete and rigorous way to prove this?

Just to confirm, you need to type at least 200 Xs? Or does it have to be exact (in which case your attempt does not suffice)?

Your idea gives: two Xs, then 8Xs, then 40Xs instead of 80. You need 16 steps using this start, not 14.

It’s at least 200 Xs

$2 + 2\times 3=8$, $8+8\times 4 = 40$, not $80$

Here's a script that solves this by brute force: https://gist.github.com/boppreh/ed35af46ab35f2bf0fb8e4220ca703fc . It found TTTTCPCPPCPPCPP (15 seconds).

Interesting! It is very similar to this problem, which already has an excellent solution by @ajotatxe and @Andrea Marino you should read first - I will use the exact same methods here.
Define $S$ with letters from C, P, and T (resp. Copy, Paste, Type) to be a string of length $n > 4$ which maximizes the amount of "X"s typed. We impose that $n > 4$ so as to not worry about degenerate cases. To solve your problem, we will find the greatest amount of "X"s typed for arbitrary $n$. Let's start off with a key observation:
$S$ starts as either TT or TTT, and then exclusively uses C or P.
That $S$ starts as either TT or TTT can be seen by brute-forcing all the possibilities when $n \leq 4$ (TTCP has 4 letters typed and 2 letters in the clipboard, while TTTC has 3 letters typed and 3 in the clipboard. Every other combination has both less letters typed and less in the clipboard). Then, since there will be at least 2 letters in the clipboard, it will always be better to paste $\geq 2$ letters than to type 1 letter.
Now, instead of thinking about the remaining portion of the string as C's and P's, it makes sense to think of it as 'blocks' of CkP's, where I use "CkP" to denote a C followed by k P's. This gives us a very useful property:
The order of these CkP's in $S$ does not matter.
Note that each CkP just multiplies the amount of "X"s, and so the order of these does not matter since multiplication is commutative. Let $A$ be the substring of $S$ after typing (so it consists exclusively of $S$'s CkP's), and define $m$ to be the length of $A$. We can think of $A$ as an unordered list of integers, with each corresponding to a particular CkP.
In particular, each of these CkP's uses k+1 letters and multiplies the amount of "X"s by k+1; Asymptotically, this means that each letter in CkP multiplies the amount of "X"s by $\sqrt[k+1]{k+1}$. The integer which maximizes this multiplication factor is $k=2$, so we expect that most of $S$ will be occupied by C2P's. And indeed, after another brute-force, we can find the optimal solution for each $m$:

If $m = 3a$, then $A$ consists exclusively of $a$ C2P's, so the number of "X"s is multiplied by $3^a$.
If $m = 3a + 1$, then $A$ consists of one C3P and $a-1$ C2P's, so the number of "X"s is multiplied by $4 \times 3^{a-1}$.
If $m = 3a + 2$, then $A$ consists of one C1P and $a$ C2P's, so the number of "X"s is multiplied by $2 \times 3^a$.

for integer $a$. Now we are almost done; we just have to consider which starting for $S$ (either TT or TTT) is optimal; We compute the possible cases in the following table:
$\begin{array} {|r|r|}\hline  & {TT} + (n - 2) & {TTT} + (n - 3) \\ \hline n = 3a & 2 \times (4 \times 3^{a-2}) & 3 \times 3^{a-1} \\ \hline n = 3a+1 & 2 \times (2 \times 3^{a-1}) & 3 \times (4 \times 3^{a-2}) \\ \hline n = 3a+2 & 2 \times 3^a & 3 \times (2 \times 3^{a-1}) \\ \hline  \end{array}$
Note that when $n = 3a + 1$ or $n = 3a + 2$, the amount of "X"s generated be either start is the same. However, for $n = 3a$, the TTT start gives slightly more "X"s, so we will use this. This gives us our formula for computing the greatest amount of "X"s for $n > 4$;
\begin{cases}
3^a,  & \text{if $n = 3a$} \\
4 \times 3^{a-1}, & \text{if $n = 3a + 1$} \\
2 \times 3^a,  & \text{if $n = 3a + 2$}
\end{cases}
Now, for $n = 14$, we can see that $S$ gives a maximum of $2 \times 3^4 = 162$ moves, while for $n = 15$ we have that $S$ gives a maximum of $3^5 = 243$ moves. Hence, the optimal number of moves to get 200 X's is 15 (and it would look like TTT followed by four C2P's, i.e TTTCPPCPPCPPCPP).
Edit: We can also find the inverse function which takes in the amount of "X"s you want to type (which I will call $m$) and outputs the minimum number of moves. This is given by
\begin{cases}
3 \lfloor \log_3m \rfloor,  & \text{if $\space\{\log_3m\} = 0$} \\
3 \lfloor \log_3m \rfloor + 1,  & \text{if $\space0 < \{\log_3m\} \leq \log_3{\frac{4}{3}}$} \\
3 \lfloor \log_3m \rfloor + 2, & \text{if $\space\log_3{\frac43} < \{\log_3m\} \leq \log_3{2}$} \\
3 \lfloor \log_3m \rfloor + 3, & \text{if $\space\log_3{2} < \{\log_3m\} < 1$}
\end{cases}
where {$x$} denotes the fractional part of $x$. Plugging in $m = 200$ gives that the minimum number of moves is 15.


Isn't 2 uses of C1P always better than C3P? Both seem to multiply by 4 using 4 characters, but the first leaves you with a bigger number in the clipboard. Although maybe it doesn't actually make a difference for optimal solutions.
Edit: Yes I see, it is better in a vaccum, but since both of these sequences are followed by a C2P or the end of the string in an optimal solution, the clipboard value doesn't matter.

I'd note for each $m$, this gives one optimal solution for a result of at least $m$ characters, but there are often many other solutions with the same optimal time.

Let $C$ denote copying, $P$ denote pasting, and $T$ denote typing. Then the sequence TTTCPPCPCPPCPCP achieves 216 Xs in 15 seconds, one second faster than the solution given above.
Worth noting is that TTTCPP gives 9 copies instead of the 8 achieved by TTCPPP at the start.
